# Real Live Search and Filter Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I'm new on Laravel and try to implement real live search and filter on my project, but it doesn't work at all. I dont understand ajax ver much and just copy paste the code from other website. I tried to understand the code and I think its correct but it doesn't work, so please help. Thanks

Here is my controller

```
 public function search(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax())
    {
        $output = '';
        $query = $request->get('query');
        if($query != '')
        {
            $data = Service::table('service')
                ->where('keterangan', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                ->orWhere('biaya', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                ->get();
        }
        else
        {
            $data = Service::table('service')
            ->orderBy('kodeService', 'asc')
            ->get();
        }
        $total_row = $data->count();
        if($total_row > 0)
        {
            foreach($data as $row)
            {
                $output .= '
                <tr>
                <td>'.$row->kodeService.'</td>
                <td>'.$row->keterangan.'</td>
                <td>'.$row->biayaService.'</td>
                </tr>
                ';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $output = '
            <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="5">No Data Found</td>
            </tr>
            ';
        }
        $data = array(
            'table_data'  => $output
        );
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

This is the script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
fetch_customer_data();
function fetch_customer_data(query = '')
{
    $.ajax({
            url:"{{ route('live_search.action') }}",
            method:'GET',
            data:{query:query},
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#table tbody').html(data.table_data);
            }
    });
}

$(document).on('keyup', '#search', function(){
    var query = $(this).val();
    fetch_customer_data(query)
});
```

});

Route :

```
Route::resource('service', 'ServiceController');
Route::get('service/search', 'Service@search')->name('live_search.action');
```

And index.blade

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Kode Service</th>
            <th>Keterangan</th>
            <th>Biaya</th>
            <th>Aksi</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($service as $data)
        <tr>
            <td><?= $data->kodeService?></td>
            <td><?= $data->keterangan ?></td>
            <td><?= $data->biayaService?></td>
            <td>

                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{{ route('service.edit', $data['kodeService']) }}"> <i class="oi oi-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><span class="oi oi-trash"></span> Hapus</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your route like this :

```
Route::get('service/search', 'ServiceController@search')->name('live_search.action');
Route::resource('service', 'ServiceController');
```

After that open the Browser Console panel (Press F12 to open it) and check the Ajax request in Network tab.

Where you can get the specific error if any in the Response tab.

Comment: If you have live url than please share with me

Comment: Also you have passed CSRF token to the request or not?

Comment: sorry, I dont have a live url and I dont know hot pass CSRF token in ajax request

Comment: Add this line in header : <meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

And this in footer after you have loaded jquery.js   <script>
//CSRF TOKEN (for Laravel)
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
</script>

Comment: have you get the success or not?

Comment: Okay, thanks. If my answer is relavant for you than please vote it and mark as correct

Answer (score 0):

If you need an extra route to your resource route,you should place the new route before the resource route.

```
 Route::get('service/search', 'ServiceController@search')->name('live_search.action');
 Route::resource('service', 'ServiceController');
```